# Process called from python hangs randomly

Tags: python, subprocess

I use Python to test a given software. In short, this is a c++ program doing some batch processing. I need to launch it with many different data sets and parameters, that's why I wrote a tool in Python. I basically launch the process, save error stream in a file, parse the output stream to get some live feedback. (The standard output stream is not very verbose.)

It mostly works as I expect, except I sometime have the tested c++ program hanging. This hang occurs only on some of my test targets, on windows XP, never on other on win 7 or some other windows XP ones. On targets where the hang can occur, the software works well if launched directly from command line.

I suspect there is a deadlock due to IO streams processing, but I don't see why.

Here is extract from my code:

```
stderrFile = open("err.txt", 'w')
stdoutFile = open("out.txt", 'w')

p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr =stderrFile, env = runEnv)
outStream = p.stdout

for line in outStream:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('======== '):
        print " - " + line[9:]
    stdoutFile.write(line + '\n')

returnCode = p.wait()
```

Comment: Have you tried running the c++ app without the python wrapper to see if the problem is there?

Comment: Yes. With it doesn't hang without python wrapper

Comment: That's really odd, I would probably debug it by printing every line first, and then adding the constraints one by one. Try with a simple "print line" in your for loop.